# Odoo V12 CE Segmentation fault (core dumped) facing this issue at the time of creating Database after the installation of Odoo 12

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-12

I am using Odoo 12 CE in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using database Postgres 9.6 I am facing this issue when I install odoo after that I browse localhost:8069/web/database/create at the time of creating a database It is showing **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** and terminate the process. The logs behalf is following:

```
shivam@shivam:~/Documents/Odoo/odoo-12.0$ ./odoo-bin
/home/shivam/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
2019-02-22 07:04:57,792 26888 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0 
2019-02-22 07:04:57,792 26888 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/shivam/.local/share/Odoo/addons/12.0', '/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-12.0/odoo/addons', '/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-12.0/addons'] 
2019-02-22 07:04:57,793 26888 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2019-02-22 07:04:58,115 26888 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
2019-02-22 07:04:58,285 26888 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on shivam.sahu:8069 
2019-02-22 07:05:04,088 26888 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
2019-02-22 07:05:04,110 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2019-02-22 07:05:04,306 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.registry: module base: creating or updating database tables 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,353 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.model.fields.relation_field_id 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,360 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.model.fields.related_field_id 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,669 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.actions.server.model_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,798 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.attachment.res_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,799 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.attachment.res_model_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,829 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.cron.cron_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:16,939 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.rule.global 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,168 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.module.module.menus_by_module 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,170 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.module.module.reports_by_module 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,172 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of ir.module.module.views_by_module 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,402 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.partner.display_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,426 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.partner.partner_share 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,429 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.partner.commercial_partner_id 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,430 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.partner.commercial_company_name 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,479 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.partner.bank.sanitized_acc_number 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,545 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.currency.decimal_places 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,595 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.company.logo_web 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,612 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.company.email 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,613 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.company.phone 
2019-02-22 07:05:17,702 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.models: Storing computed values of res.users.share 
2019-02-22 07:05:18,333 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res.lang.csv 
2019-02-22 07:05:18,496 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_lang_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:18,520 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_partner_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:18,819 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_company_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:18,857 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_users_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:19,108 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/report_paperformat_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:19,129 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_currency_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:20,128 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_country_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:23,669 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/ir_demo_data.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:23,714 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/security/base_groups.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:24,068 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/security/base_security.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:24,368 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/base_menus.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:24,640 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/res_config_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:24,693 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res.country.state.csv 
2019-02-22 07:05:25,349 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_actions_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:25,865 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_config_parameter_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:25,958 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_cron_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:26,113 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_filters_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:26,217 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_mail_server_views.xml 
2019-02-22 07:05:26,322 26888 INFO odoo-12 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/views/ir_model_views.xml 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install pip3 and then

install the requirements.txt in the odoo root

sudo python3 -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably issue with installed `psycopg2`, try installing latest `psycopg2-binary` package.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.
I get this error I didn't run the requirements.txt file for file